# Prefer one of multiple declarations with same name

Tags: c++, namespaces, shadowing

Suppose I have the following code

```
namespace A {
    int foo();
}
namespace B {
    void foo();
}
using namespace A;
using namespace B;


int x = foo(); // error
```

and I find `A::foo` really useful, but am not that into `B::foo`. Is there anything I can do to cause `A::foo` to be preferred upon subsequent unqualified references to `foo`? E.g. `using A::foo` (which in reality has no effect), or `unusing B::foo`.

Comment: You have namespace A and B and you want to prefer A::foo then what you have to do is to remove both `using namespace` statements and then in function where you want to prefer A::foo use `using A::foo` and then calling `foo()` will result in foo function of A

Comment: This is not a good answer--See SergeyA's answer below--so it's a comment. You can (and should) explicitly state the namespace: `int x = A::foo();` This eliminates the need for `using namespace` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of having a namespace is to isolate names. By `using` the whole namespace you defy this very reason.

Solution to your problem is to stop `using namespace` once and for all, and never return to this deplorable tactic.

Comment: Or do it in limited scopes, i.e `int main() { using namespace A; ... }`

Comment: @sleeptightpupper, I am yet to see any reason to use the whole namespace, even in narrow enough scope.

Comment: But do it intelligently in limited scopes. `int main() { using namespace A; using namespace A; int x = foo(); }` leaves OP no better off. Until you know what you are doing and can justify `using namespace <insert namespace here>`, don't do it.

Comment: @SergeyA, What about with `std::literals::chrono_literals`? Don't you have to use a `using` directive to make them visible?

Comment: @AidenDeom, fair enough, this is a reason.